# How to determine Magento custom extension url

Tags: php, magento, url-routing

I am having any issue with finding the correct url for one of my pages that I created for my extension. I just receive a 404.

Here are the basics of what I have. I am trying `extension/share/` but I get a 404.

**controllers/EventController.php**

```
<?php

class My_Extension_EventController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

/**************  Some Code *****************/

}
```

**block/Share.php**

```
<?php
class My_Extension_Block_share extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

/**************  Some Code *****************/

}
```

**extensionlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <my_extension_event_share>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="extension.share" type="my_extension/share" template="extension/share.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </my_extension_event_share>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out. I did not have my layout properly formatted.

```
    <my_extension_share_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="extension.share" type="my_extension/share" template="extension/share.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </my_extension_share_index>
```

The above code will tell Magento the URL should be extension/share/

Hope that helps someone. :)

```
$Magento = "Trial and Error with huge headache!"
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL in Magento has 3 components:

1. module name (required)
2. controller name (optional)
3. action name (optional)

These are separated by / in the URL: domain.com/modulename/controllername/actionname

The module name is defined in the extension config file, /etc/config.xml. In the following example, **myext** is the module name:

```
<config>
    .
    .
    .
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <myext>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Extension</module>
                    <frontName>myext</frontName>
                </args>
            </emgs>
            .
            .
            .
```

The controller name and action name are optional, when not included, the default is index. So the following URLs are the same:

- domain.com/myext/
- domain.com/myext/index/index/

The controller name is the file path and file name of the PHP file that contains the controller code. For example, **car_pedal** is the controller name for this file:

```
../My/Extension/controllers/Car/PedalController.php
```

So, now the URL is **domain.com/myext/car_pedal/**

Lastly, the action name is the function defined within the controller. For example, **brake** is the action name in the following example:

```
<?php
class My_Extension_Car_PedalController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{  
    public function brakeAction()
    {      
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

The complete URL is now formed: **domain.com/myext/car_pedal/brake**.  When the URL is received by Magento, it will pass the control to the function brakeAction. This is the C in MVC, Model-View-Controler.

Depending on what we want to do in the brakeAction, the response can be pure text, for example, a response for AJAX:

```
public function brakeAction()
{      
    return $this->getResponse()->setBody('Not Implemented Yet');
}
```

Or we can construct a complete HTML page based on Magento block. This is the V in MVC. The view in Magento can be defined in 3 places:

1. layout as XML code (optional)
2. block class as PHP code (required)
3. design template as HTML and PHP code, the .phtml file (optional)

What you have done is utilized all 3 of the above. And your question really is how to construct the handle in the layout for the controller action so you can simply do this:

```
public function brakeAction()
{      
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And voila, a complete HTML page with header, footer, body, etc. is automatically generated and return to the browser.

In my example, the handles are:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">    
    <myext_index_index>
        <!-- for indexAction in My_Extension_IndexController -->
    </myext_index_index>
    <myext_car_pedal_index>
        <!-- for indexAction in My_Extension_Car_PedalController  -->
    </myext_car_pedal_index>
    <myext_car_pedal_brake>
        <!-- for brakeAction in My_Extension_Car_PedalController  -->
    </myext_car_pedal_brake>
</layout>
```

I hope that helps.